# Packer is targeting the wrong host's IP

Tags: ansible, packer

I use packer to create images on AWS.
When Packer runs this Ansible part:

```
   - name: Wait for reboot to finish
     local_action: wait_for host={{ ansible_host }} port=22 state=started
```

I get "Timeout when waiting for 127.0.0.1:22"

Why "ansible_host" is set to "127.0.0.1" instead of the provisioned host's IP?

How to tell Packer to use the right "ansible_host"?

```
Packer version: 1.2.4
Ansible version: 2.5.4
```

Comment: What is your inventory? Are you creating one when the installation finishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's vaguely described in the ingress of the [documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html):

> It dynamically creates an Ansible inventory file configured to use
>   SSH, runs an SSH server, executes ansible-playbook, and marshals
>   Ansible plays through the SSH server to the machine being provisioned
>   by Packer.

This means that the ansible target (`ansible_host`) is local host but with a different port and then this forwarded to the correct host.

Basically you can't have reboots (or restarts of sshd) in your playbook when running Packer, since the ssh session will be disconnected. See [Handeling Reboots - Shell Provisioner](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell.html#handling-reboots) for more information.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Packer. The variable is `ansible_host`

Comment: It certainly does, Packer creates the inventory file and executes ansible targeting the ssh proxy.

I'm one or the maintainers of Packer, https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/graphs/contributors

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I must reboot the instance with packer, is there a workaround?

Comment: Us the shell provisioner.

Comment: Thanks @RickardvonEssen for the explanation. Everyday I learn from this site and you guys.